# How to find the value in which an expression becomes greater than another

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations, inequalities

I have the following expressions:

$\Delta \sigma_1=\frac{2 \gamma ^2 \left(\text{$\sigma $Y} \log \left(\frac{\gamma }{\alpha }\right)+\text{pe}\right)}{\left(\gamma ^2-1\right) \rho ^2}$

$\Delta \sigma_2=\frac{\frac{P}{\pi  b^2}-\frac{\gamma ^2 \left(\rho ^2+1\right) \text{$\sigma $Y} \log \left(\frac{\gamma }{\alpha }\right)+\text{pe} \left(\gamma ^2+\rho ^2\right)}{\rho ^2}}{\gamma ^2-1}$

$\Delta \sigma_3=\frac{-\frac{\gamma ^2 \left(\rho ^2-1\right) \text{$\sigma $Y} \log \left(\frac{\gamma }{\alpha }\right)}{\rho ^2}+\frac{P}{\pi  b^2}+\text{pe} \left(\frac{\gamma ^2}{\rho ^2}-1\right)}{\gamma ^2-1}$

I need to find the greater between $\Delta \sigma_1$ and $\Delta \sigma_2$.
Then I have to compare the max expression just found with $\Delta \sigma_3$, in order to find for which value of $\gamma$ the following inequality is satisfied:

max$(\Delta \sigma_1$, $\Delta \sigma_2)\geq \Delta \sigma_3$.

Note that: (P, pe, b, $\sigma_Y$, $\alpha=a/b$ are constant parameters; $\rho=r/b$ can be assumed as $\rho=\gamma$ and $\gamma=c/b$ is defined in $]\alpha;1]$

Thanks to everyone who will help me.

`\[CapitalDelta]\[Sigma]el1 =(2 \[Gamma]^2 (pe + \[Sigma]Y Log[\[Gamma]/\[Alpha]]))/((-1 + \
\[Gamma]^2) \[Rho]^2)`

`\[CapitalDelta]\[Sigma]el2 =(P/(b^2 \[Pi]) - (
 pe (\[Gamma]^2 + \[Rho]^2) + \[Gamma]^2 (1 + \[Rho]^2) \[Sigma]Y \
Log[\[Gamma]/\[Alpha]])/\[Rho]^2)/(-1 + \[Gamma]^2)`

`\[CapitalDelta]\[Sigma]el3 =(P/(b^2 \[Pi]) + 
 pe (-1 + \[Gamma]^2/\[Rho]^2) - (\[Gamma]^2 (-1 + \[Rho]^2) \
\[Sigma]Y Log[\[Gamma]/\[Alpha]])/\[Rho]^2)/(-1 + \[Gamma]^2)`

```
Simplify[Solve[\[CapitalDelta]\[Sigma]el2 - \[CapitalDelta]\[Sigma]el3 == 0 && \[Alpha] <= \[Gamma] <= 1, \[Gamma]], Assumptions -> {pe > 0, b > 0, P > 0, \[Sigma]Y > 0, \[Alpha] > 0}]
```

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica or a purely math question?

Comment: Both. I've tried to plot the first two expression (fixing certain magnitude of the others parameters). Found the greatest (say $\Delta \sigma_2$) I' ve tried to Solve[$\Delta \sigma_2 - \Delta \sigma_3 == 0 , \gamma$], but it doesn't work. Neither using Simplify and some Assumptions for the parameters.

Comment: Then please provide a valid code to work with.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Hope this works:

Comment: @koda Try to edit your answer. To show your code: "To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces or surround with groups of backticks"

Comment: Sorry, again, I've just edited the post, with the code at the end. Should I have to add anything else?

Comment: The three expressions only depend on `{b, P, pe, \[Alpha], \[Gamma], \[Rho], \[Sigma]Y}` . Is it possible to further reduce the set of parameters? Can we assume `\[Gamma] == \[Rho]`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The other parameters (the pressure P,pe and $\sigma_Y$ as well as the geometrical b and $\alpha$ are constant. I tried a numerical solution, but I need to develope a general criteria, for any magnitude of them, with the assumptions above)

Comment: Assuming `P=0` and observing  `P/b^2` you can reduce the number of parameters to `{ \[Sigma]Y/(P/b^2),pe/(P/b^2),\[Alpha],\[Gamma]}`: 4 parameters instead of 7!  RegionPlot3D might visualize the parameter region of  your inequality for different `\[Alpha]`...

Comment: P cannot be zero neither pe, $\sigma_Y$.